Is this possible in one statement?
const where = {
  office_no: 1999,
  status: "APPLY",
  [Op.and]: [
    Sequelize.literal(
      `${property_master_no} member of (request_json->'$.property[*].property_master_no')`,
    ),
  ],
};

if (document_no) {
  where["no"] = {
    [Op.not]: document_no,
  };
}

I want to make if in const where.
Sorry. I don't have any idea.

It is indeed is possible by the use of combined spread and ternary operator
 const where = {
        office_no: 1999,
        status: 'APPLY,
        [Op.and]: [
            Sequelize.literal(`${property_master_no} member of (request_json->'$.property[*].property_master_no')`)
        ],
        ...(document_no ? { 'no': { [Op.not]: document_no } } : {})
    }

